# How to modify steps for deploying a Rails 7 app using Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a toy Rails 7 app using these instructions:
https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine; however, the process fails in Step 2. If I understand the messages below, I need to add the command

`bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux`

to the install process. However, I don't see where I specify the install process (e.g., which bundler commands to run). The instructions simply say to create `app.yaml` then run `gcloud app deploy`.

```
Step #2: [DEPRECATED] The `--deployment` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set --local deployment 'true'`, and stop using this flag
Step #2: [DEPRECATED] The `--without` flag is deprecated because it relies on being remembered across bundler invocations, which bundler will no longer do in future versions. Instead please use `bundle config set --local without 'development test'`, and stop using this flag
Step #2: Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-23"] but your local platform
Step #2: is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with
Step #2: `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
Step #2: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash' returned a non-zero code: 16
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:b30a2bedbbd24823a41fe768379ab8dd362cd71c0eb6cfd6de58b225805e4c13" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 16
Step #2:
```

Comment: you don't run it during install, you run `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` to update your lock file before deploying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki so others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @dbugger:

> you don't run it during install, you run `bundle lock --add-platform x86\_64-linux` to update your lock file before deploying